# find first row based on a cycle size

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table of cards and a table of moves (on a card), like:

```
declare @cards table
(
    id_card int,
    cycle int
)

insert into @cards (id_card, cycle) values (1, 10)

declare @moves table
(
    id_move int,
    id_card int,
    quantity int
)

insert into @moves (id_move, id_card, quantity) values (1, 1, 2)
insert into @moves (id_move, id_card, quantity) values (2, 1, 4)
insert into @moves (id_move, id_card, quantity) values (3, 1, 2)
insert into @moves (id_move, id_card, quantity) values (4, 1, 8)
insert into @moves (id_move, id_card, quantity) values (5, 1, 2)
```

The problem: each card gets a cycle size, and each move gets a quantity. So, a card cycle size 10 and 18 moves means 1 full cycle plus 8 moves. I have to find the last cycle first move (the move id 4 in the given example). The problem sounds (at first) trivial, but I'm getting so many troubles to find the move that I think I'm doing something very wrong.

I came up with a query that gives where the last cycle first move starts position, but I'm not finding anywhere to go from there.

```
select
    id_card,
    case
        when value > quantity then value - quantity
        else value
    end value
from
(
    select
        f.id_card,
        f.quantity,
        f.quantity - f.quantity % cards.cycle + 1 value
    from
    (
        select
            id_card,
            sum(quantity) quantity
        from @moves
        group by
            id_card
    ) f
    join @cards cards on
        cards.id_card = f.id_card
) f
```

Expected output:

```
id_move
4
```

Any ideas? I can make any modifications to make the problem easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
;WITH CycleCountCTE AS (
SELECT m.id_move, m.id_card, (select sum(quantity)-1 FROM @moves m2 WHERE m2.id_card = m.id_card AND m2.id_move<=m.id_move)/c.cycle + 1 AS CycleNum, 
    (SELECT MAX(m3.id_move) FROM @moves m3 WHERE m3.id_card = m.id_card AND m3.id_move < m.id_move) AS Prev_id_move
FROM @cards c
JOIN @moves m on m.id_card = c.id_card
)
SELECT cn.id_card, MAX(cn.id_move) as First_id_move_of_last_cycle
FROM CycleCountCTE cn
LEFT OUTER JOIN CycleCountCTE cp ON cp.id_move = cn.Prev_id_move
where cn.CycleNum > isnull(cp.CycleNum,0)
GROUP BY cn.id_card
```

Or a bit simpler:

```
;WITH CycleCountCTE AS (
SELECT m.id_move, m.id_card, (select sum(quantity)-1 FROM @moves m2 WHERE m2.id_card = m.id_card AND m2.id_move<=m.id_move)/c.cycle + 1 AS CycleNum
FROM @cards c
JOIN @moves m on m.id_card = c.id_card
)
SELECT id_card, MIN(id_move) as First_id_move_of_last_cycle
FROM CycleCountCTE c
WHERE CycleNum = (SELECT MAX(CycleNum) from CycleCountCTE c2 WHERE c2.id_card = c.id_card)
GROUP BY id_card
```

Comment: I'm still trying to understand what you did there but if you have 10 moves the last cycle first move should be the first one, but it still gives the last one.

Comment: Good idea, I'm trying to change it to get the correct id move when the moves quantity is a multiple of the cycle size.

Comment: I added another way to do it.  Both worked.  In the first one I took the maximum id_move where its cyclenum was greater than the previous one.

Comment: But if the moves quantity is a multiple of the cycle, it gives me the wrong id move. It's because `moves quantity / cycle + 1` is wrong if the the remainder is 0. In this case we should not put the plus one. I'm gonna fix it.

Comment: Wait, I think it should be SUM(quantity)-1.  I updated the query with that.

Comment: The +1 was really just aesthetic (so that the first CycleNum would be 1 rather than 0).  The real mistake was the off-by-one error so that a multiple of the cycle quantity is the end of the last cycle rather than the beginning of the next one.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this, I believe it may be what you are looking for.  It takes a running total of the card's quantity and returns the remainder of the cycle as the current_cycle.

```
SELECT 
    m.[id_move],
    m.[id_card],
    m.[quantity],
    c.[cycle],
    running_total_set.[total_quantity],
    running_total_set.[total_quantity] % c.[cycle] AS [current_cycle]
FROM @moves m
INNER JOIN @cards c
    ON m.[id_card] = c.[id_card]
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        id_move_2 AS [id_move],
        SUM([quantity]) AS [total_quantity]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            moves1.id_move AS [id_move_1],
            moves2.id_move AS [id_move_2],
            moves1.quantity AS [quantity]
        FROM @moves moves1
        INNER JOIN @moves moves2
            ON moves2.[id_move] >= moves1.[id_move]
    )move_set
    GROUP BY [id_move_2]
)running_total_set
ON m.[id_move] = running_total_set.[id_move]
```

Comment: I'm glad you put your mind on this, but I don't think you got it. I have to find the last cycle first move (the move id 4 in the given example). And I think you got the cycle thing wrong. If the cycle is 10 and I have 32 moves, I have 3 full cycle and 2 moves.

Comment: My query gives the last cycle first move starts position, and I think I can use your running total idea.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd start by setting up a secondary moves table that logs the total number of previous moves:

```
SELECT this.id_move, this.id_card, this.quantity,
  [sumPrevMoves] = sum(prev.quantity),
  [sumMovesNow] = this.quantity + isnull(sum(prev.quantity), 0)
FROM @moves this
  LEFT JOIN @moves prev on this.id_card = prev.id_card
                       and this.id_move > prev.id_move
GROUP BY this.id_move, this.id_card, this.quantity
```

Then, with a simple join to the @cards table you can find all kinds of useful things:

```
SELECT m.id_move, m.id_card,
  [cardCycles] = c.cycle,
  [thisMove] = m.quantity,
  m.sumPrevMoves, m.sumMovesNow,
  [totalCycles] = m.sumMovesNow / cycle,
  [totalMoves] = m.sumMovesNow % cycle
FROM @cards c
  JOIN (/*query from above*/) m on c.id_card = m.id_card
```

from here, to find the `last cycle, first move`, you need two pieces of info:

1. What was the final cycle count
2. What was the minimum move of that cycle

If you put everything together with some CTEs, the following should give you what you want:

```
;WITH moves2 as (
    SELECT this.id_move, this.id_card, this.quantity,
      [sumPrevMoves] = sum(prev.quantity),
      [sumMovesNow] = this.quantity + isnull(sum(prev.quantity), 0)
    FROM @moves this
      LEFT JOIN @moves prev on this.id_card = prev.id_card
                           and this.id_move > prev.id_move
    GROUP BY this.id_move, this.id_card, this.quantity
), allMoves as (
    SELECT m.id_move, m.id_card,
      [cardCycles] = c.cycle,
      [thisMove] = m.quantity,
      m.sumPrevMoves, m.sumMovesNow,
      [totalCycles] = m.sumMovesNow / cycle,
      [totalMoves] = m.sumMovesNow % cycle
    FROM @cards c
      JOIN moves2 m on c.id_card = m.id_card
)
SELECT am1.id_card, [firstMoveLastCycle] = min(am1.id_move)
FROM allMoves am1
    join (
        SELECT id_card, [lastCycle] = max(totalCycles)
        FROM allMoves
        GROUP BY id_card
    ) am2 on am1.id_card=am2.id_card
        and am1.totalCycles = am2.lastCycle
GROUP BY am1.id_card
```

Comment: Thank you for put on mind on this. I'm testing it and it's working except when the moves quantity is a multiplier of the cycle size, like 20 moves and cycle 10. I gave it for GilM anyways, because his solution looks more elegant. Thank you again.